# hibernate HQL error for update query when use join on

Tags: hibernate, hql

when execute this query in hibernate getting error of "org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 132". can anyone help me on my code how to use ON for hibernate.

```
Session session  = (Session) em1.getDelegate();

org.hibernate.Query q=session.createQuery("UPDATE sc_ob_temp_audit set export_flag ='Y' WHERE audit_id IN(select a.audit_id FROM sc_ob_temp_audit a JOIN sc_ob_allocation b  ON a.sc_ob_profile_code = b.sc_ob_profile_code AND a.sc_orig_country= b.sc_orig_country LEFT OUTER JOIN sc_fac_group f ON   b.sc_orig_country = f.sc_orig_country AND b.sc_orig_sf_group_code = f.sc_fac_group_code LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT e.gp_cnt_cd,d.sc_prod_cont_code,d.sc_prod_group_code,d.sc_orig_country, e.gp_cd FROM sc_ob_prod_group d LEFT OUTER JOIN gbl_product e ON d.sc_prod_cont_code = e. gp_cnt_cd)de ON b.sc_orig_country = de.sc_orig_country AND b.sc_prod_cont_group_code=de.sc_prod_group_code WHERE a.sc_orig_country=:countryCd AND a.export_flag= 'N')");

q.setParameter("countryCd", country.trim());

q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how `HQL` works - this is not how you join in `HQL`. Please read up on [HQL join syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms). Remember this is **not** `SQL`.

Comment: Without knowledge of you hibernate mappings I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to execute an SQL query - to do so you have to use the [SQLQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html) object instead. To get an `SQLQuery` object just call `session.createSqlQuery`

On the other hand - why are you using Hibernate if you just end up writing SQL statements? Have you mapped the `sc_ob_temp_audit` table?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your query it does not seems an hql. It looks like an sql query.
use session.createSqlSquery instead session.createQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn more about HQL syntax first..

**See also:**

- [16.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)